# How do I find how many integers fall into a range[a...b] in O(1) time using python?

Tags: python

I have the following code and I am trying to figure out how to find how many integers fall into a range[a...b] in O(1) time using python after the array has been sorted using Counting Sort. I am supposed to sort the array and then see how many integers fall in the range.

```
def CountingSort(A, B, k):
   
    C = [0] * (k+1)
    for x in range(k+1): C[k] = 0

   
    for j in range(0,len(A)): 
        C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1

   
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1]
    
   
    for j in range(len(A)-1, -1, -1):
        B[C[A[j]]-1] = A[j]
        C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] - 1



arr=[ 3, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2 ]
res=[0] * (len(arr))

CountingSort(arr, res, 5)

print(res)

a = int(input("Enter value for a (lower value) in range:"))
b = int(input("Enter value for b (higher value) in range:"))
print("The value for A entered is:",a)
print("The value for B entered is:",b)
def CountRange(a,b):

 
 for a,b in range ((len(res))):
   
        return res[b] - res[a-1]

CountRange(a,b)
```

I am unsure of how to do the counting in range part. I know that to achieve it I need to do C[B] – C[A-1] but I am unsure of how to do that in the function as I am new to python.

Do I have to create another function or can I just continue with the CountingSort function?

When I try the above code I get the following error: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counting sort algorithm has a part that is useful: it counts frequencies in `C`. But then it does not return that information, but only returns a sorted list. The sorted list is not going to help you achieve a time complexity of O(1) for a range count.

You should use the frequency of each value to calculate a running sum. That way you know for each value how many numbers come *before* it (in sorted order). *That* is the info you need, not so much the sorted list. With that running frequency sum info you can do the subtraction without any loop:

```
def count_less(lst, high):
    res = [0] * (high+1)

    for val in lst:
        res[val] += 1

    # make running sum
    running = 0
    for val, count in enumerate(res):
        running += count
        res[val] = running
    return res

def count_range(res, a, b):
    return res[b] - (res[a-1] if a > 0 else 0)

lst=[ 3, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2 ]
res=[0] * len(lst)

res = count_less(lst, 5)

print(res)

a = int(input("Enter value for a (lower value) in range:"))
b = int(input("Enter value for b (higher value) in range:"))
print("The value for A entered is:",a)
print("The value for B entered is:",b)

print(count_range(res, a, b))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works, but I am required to sort the list first as it uses the CountingSort algorithm.

Comment: *"I am required"*: you should clearly set out our restrictions in the question.

Comment: I thought I did, apologies

Comment: But there is no reason why you cannot call your CountingSort function first. Just call it, and then go on with this code. The point is that counting sort is not going to bring you any closer if you are not going to count frequencies of each number. And that you can do as well on an unsorted as on a sorted list. It doesn't matter.

Comment: If you are only going to rely on the sorted list, then it is not possible to do the job in O(1). You need to get the frequencies, and store a running sum.

Comment: Oh ok. I believe I was counting the frequencies through my counting sort function because I thought counting sort counts the frequencies of each number.

Comment: Yes, you count the frequencies, but you don't use that info for anything else than sorting, while you should actually use it to make a running sum, not sort the list.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I thought that counting sort sorted the list and then I can answer any query about how many of the integers fall in that range.

Comment: No, a sorted list can only help to perform binary searches, which are still O(logn). For 0(1) range count, you really need the running sum.

Comment: Oh ok, so I was missing the running sum from my code to get O(1). Thank you very much for your help and explanation. I am starting to understand where I went wrong.